# How to remove Dom Element by TagName or Id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below DOM element is created. I want to remove `id="test"` DOM element.

I tried by removing by Index as below.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[2].remove();
```

***How I can remove which DOM have id="test" ?***

[image]

Comment: Search for how to select an element by its ID. I mean, you should get answers that go back at least two decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```js
document.getElementById("test").remove();
```